# POST JSON ignoring content-type

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Using ColdFusion, I am trying to POST JSON to an API. Here is the code I have so far -

```
<cfhttp url="#url#" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(jsonStr)#">
</cfhttp>
```

An example of the JSON is here -

```
{
  "booking":{
      "username"            : "#username#",
      "password"            : "#password#",
      "customerEmail"       : "#customer_email_address#",
      "firstName"           : "#customer_firstname#",
      "lastName"            : "#customer_surname#",
      "telephoneNumber"     : "#customer_mobile_number#",
      "guestNumber"         : #url.guests#,
      "unitNumber"      : #url.location#,
      "eventDate"       : "#LSDateFormat(url.when,'dd/mm/yyyy')#"
   }
 }
```

When I pass this JSON to the API URL with POSTMAN client in Chrome, everything is good! however when I process this in CF, I simply get a bad request error from the API. I realise that message is no use that is simple whats being set in the API.

If I remove the content-type from POSTMAN client in Chrome, I get the same message. So I am "assuming" That the content-type is not being sent or over written somehow in CF.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I may be off, but the variable you're Serializing into JSON is called jsonStr. It's not already a string is it? If not, my weapon of choice in debugging http traffic is Fiddler. Amend your cfhttp call to use fiddler as a proxy (localhost 8888) and capture the call coldfusion makes, then compare it to the one POSTMAN makes and you can confirm that the content-type is the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the API not accepting what I thought it required.